# How can I map Sql File Table in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, filetable

Recently the company I work for used SQL Server `FileTable`s. How can I map these tables in Entity Framework Core? This is one of them:

[image]

I've searched. There are some solutions like creating a stored procedure and so on. But unfortunately I cannot create any stored procedure or view or any other table.

I'm using C# 8.0, .NET Core 3.1 and EF Core 5.0

Comment: Scaffolding doesn't work?

Comment: No. It says:
Could not find type mapping for column 'biz.ProductMerchantsImages.path_locator' with data type 'hierarchyid'. Skipping column.
...

Comment: Does your EF Core project use [EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#entityframeworkcoresqlserverhierarchyid)?

Comment: It solved column mapping problem. Thanks. But table mapping problem is still alive.

Comment: "But table mapping problem is still alive". do you get any error?

Comment: Yes.
"Could not scaffold the primary key for 'biz.ProductMerchantsImages'. The following columns in the primary key could not be scaffolded: path_locator." 

"Unable to generate entity type for table 'biz.ProductMerchantsImages' since its primary key could not be scaffolded."